# Find value in associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an associative array using following function.

```
function checkEmpty(){

            var sizes = new Array();
            var validate = new Array();
            $j('div.option-fields').each(function(){
                if($j(this).attr('id')) {

                    sizes.push($j(this).attr('id'));
                }

            });
            for(var i=0; i< sizes.size(); i++){
                $j("#"+sizes[i]+' input[type=text]').each(function(){
                    if($j(this).val()){
                        //validate.push(true);
                        validate[sizes[i]] = true;  
                    }else{
                        //validate.push(false);
                        validate[sizes[i]] = false;
                    }
                });

            }
}
```

which return [size-278: true, size-287: true]

Now I want to search whether this result contain false in value or not,
or whether all value with different indexes are same or not.

I used inArray but it is giving -1 every time.

Comment: well you really do not have an array.....

Comment: `sizes.size()` is a syntax error. It's `sizes.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better that `validate` will be an Hash rather than Array

Search Associative Arrays here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

so declare it like this:

`var validate = {};`

Than you will get something like this {size-278: true, size-287: true}

And you can look for false value like this:

```js
var validate = {'size-278': true, 'size-287': true};
var values = Object.values(validate);
console.log(values.indexOf(false));

var validate = {'size-278': true, 'size-287': true};
var values = Object.values(validate);
console.log(values.indexOf(true));
```

Notice that `Object.values` may not be supported in older browser

Comment: You can also loo throught the keys _for(let c in validate){console.log(validate[c])}_

Answer (score 1):

To search for an a value within an associative array, you do it like so:

```
listOfLanguagesAndTheirSubtags = {"Afrikaans" : "AF", "Dansk" : "DA", "Deutsch": "DE", "English": "EN",  "Italiano" : "IT" }; 
var values = Object.values(listOfLanguagesAndTheirSubtags);
var subtagToFind = "AF"; 
if(values.includes(subtagToFind))
{
   console.log('value is found');
}
else
{
   console.log('value NOT found'); 
}
```

To search whether all values with different indices are the same or not, you can go further like so:

```
var numberOfOccurencesOfSubtag = values.filter(function(value){
return value === subtagToFind;}).length 
if(numberOfOccurencesOfSubtag === values.length)
{
    console.log("All values with different indices are the same");//... as subtagToFind
}
else
{
    console.log("All values with different indices are NOT the same");//... as subtagToFind
}
```